# Валидация в Laravel на основе длины другого поля

Tags: laravel, валидация, laravel-8

Хочу сделать поле "Краткое название" обязательным для заполнения, если значение поля "Название" имеет длину более 300 символов. Может кто-то подобное уже реализовывал?

Пытаюсь написать правило валидации, гугл не помогает.

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё есть в документации в разделе валидация. Используйте фасад `Rule`. В качестве входного параметра должна быть функция возвращающая `bool` или просто значение с типом `bool`

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

...

$request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|string|min:10',
    'slug' => [
        'string',
        'nullable',
        Rule::requiredIf(mb_strlen($request->name) >= 300)
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ

Comment: @КонстантинКазначеев пожалуйста